Connect existing Cloud SQL Database to Replit
I'm just starting w/Replit, and I want my webapp to be able to connect to my existing Google Cloud SQL DB.  To do this, I need to authorize replit to connect, but I don't want to allow all (0.0.0.0) connections to the DB, and I can't see where replit defines an IP range.  What's the best approach?

I don't know much about Replit, but if you're writing in Python or Node.js, you could use the Cloud SQL Python Connector or the Node.js Connector:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-nodejs-connector

The Connectors allow you to establish a secure connection to your public IP Cloud SQL instance without having to allowlist CIDR ranges.
The challenge would be to configure credentials. I would guess you could use Secrets to store a service account key and use that for your credentials.
